# Comma usage for clarity

Tags: grammar, commas

Which of these sentences is correct? A comma is added to the second but does it suggest that the "to remove this block" is nonessential etc?

> These users will not be allocated a licence by Contoso, to remove this block click remove next to the user below.
>
> These users will not be allocated a licence by Contoso, to remove this block **,** click remove next to the user below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither:  *These users will not be allocated a licence by Contoso; to remove this block, click remove next to the user below.*

The semicolon here separates the sentence into two related phrases.  You could use a full stop instead, but the semicolon tells the reader that the second phrase is some additional information to do with the first phrase, or, if you prefer, it tells the reader "Hold this first phrase in your mind - it gives you the context for the section after the semicolon."

Comment: You might also want to put the second "remove" (after "click") in double-quotes and/or a different font/style (and probably capitilised).

Comment: @TripeHound all of those, I'd say, if we're thinking about software design rather than strictly about English language :)

Comment: Doh - and now it seems so obvious, thanks! @TripeHound: that's useful too :)